# Oracle join view for best matches

Tags: sql, oracle, join, view, union

I wish to create a view which joins two tables together.

T1 =

```
Col1 Col2
AA   BB
EE   FF
YY   ZZ
11   00
```

T2 =

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
AA   BB   1
AA   CC   2
CC   BB   3
GG   FF   4
GG   HH   5
EE   HH   6
XX   YY   7
XX   WW   8
YY   RR   9
```

The rules for this view are a Best match scenario based upon the following rules:

```
1. Return Col3 from T2 if T1.Col1 & T1.Col2 = T2.Col1 & T2.Col2
ELSE
2. Return Col3 if T1.Col2 = T2.Col2
ELSE
3. Return Col3 if T1.Col = T2.Col1
ELSE
4. Return NULL
```

So in these examples I would expect the final view to contain:

```
AA BB 1   (Rule 1 match)
EE FF 4   (Rule 2 match)
YY ZZ 9   (Rule 3 match)
11 00 NULL (Rule 4 match)
```

The difficulty I am having is in the cases where it hits multiple rules (e.g. Rows 1 and 3 where rules 1 and 2 are hit or Rows 4 and 6 where rules 2 and 3 are hit separately).

I realise in this example that Rule 3 is hit multiple times - this is fine as the idea is it will only hit rule 3 when the other rules aren't true which *should* only ever yield 1 result (like in example 3).

Is there a way to do a similar union to cater for these cascading rules or will additional views need to creating with pre-filtering (such as having count < 2)?

A formula for this in excel would be:
=IF(AND(A3=$F$2,B3=$G$2),"Rule1",IF((B3=$G$2),"Rule 2",IF((A3=$F$2),"Rule 3","NULL")))

Where A3 = T2.Col1, B3 = T2.Col2 G2 = T1.Col2 and F2 = T1.Col1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
with t1 as (select 'AA' col1, 'BB' col2 from dual union all
            select 'EE' col1, 'FF' col2 from dual union all
            select 'YY' col1, 'ZZ' col2 from dual union all
            select '11' col1, '00' col2 from dual),
     t2 as (select 'AA' col1, 'BB' col2, 1 col3 from dual union all
            select 'AA' col1, 'CC' col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
            select 'CC' col1, 'BB' col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
            select 'GG' col1, 'FF' col2, 4 col3 from dual union all
            select 'GG' col1, 'HH' col2, 5 col3 from dual union all
            select 'EE' col1, 'HH' col2, 6 col3 from dual union all
            select 'XX' col1, 'YY' col2, 7 col3 from dual union all
            select 'XX' col1, 'WW' col2, 8 col3 from dual union all
            select 'YY' col1, 'RR' col2, 9 col3 from dual),
    res as (select t1.col1,
                   t1.col2,
                   t2.col3,
                   case when t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2 then 1
                        when t1.col2 = t2.col2 then 2
                        when t1.col1 = t2.col1 then 3
                   end join_level,
                   min (case when t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2 then 1
                             when t1.col2 = t2.col2 then 2
                             when t1.col1 = t2.col1 then 3
                        end) over (partition by t1.col1, t1.col2) min_join_level
            from   t1
                   left outer join t2 on (t1.col1 = t2.col1 or t1.col2 = t2.col2))
select col1,
       col2,
       col3
from   res
where  join_level = min_join_level
or     join_level is null;


COL1 COL2       COL3
---- ---- ----------
11   00                                       
AA   BB            1
EE   FF            4
YY   ZZ            9
```

Ie. do the joins first (in this case, `t1 left outer join t2 on (t2.col1 = t1.col1 or t2.col2 = t1.col2)` includes rows where `t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2`), and then filter the results based on which join condition takes precedence.

---

Here's a slightly different alternative, using aggregates instead of analytic functions like the above answer:

```
with t1 as (select 'AA' col1, 'BB' col2 from dual union all
            select 'EE' col1, 'FF' col2 from dual union all
            select 'YY' col1, 'ZZ' col2 from dual union all
            select '11' col1, '00' col2 from dual),
     t2 as (select 'AA' col1, 'BB' col2, 1 col3 from dual union all
            select 'AA' col1, 'CC' col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
            select 'CC' col1, 'BB' col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
            select 'GG' col1, 'FF' col2, 4 col3 from dual union all
            select 'GG' col1, 'HH' col2, 5 col3 from dual union all
            select 'EE' col1, 'HH' col2, 6 col3 from dual union all
            select 'XX' col1, 'YY' col2, 7 col3 from dual union all
            select 'XX' col1, 'WW' col2, 8 col3 from dual union all
            select 'YY' col1, 'RR' col2, 9 col3 from dual)
select t1.col1,
       t1.col2,
       min(t2.col3) keep (dense_rank first order by case when t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2 then 1
                                                         when t1.col2 = t2.col2 then 2
                                                         when t1.col1 = t2.col1 then 3
                                                    end) col3
from   t1
       left outer join t2 on (t1.col1 = t2.col1 or t1.col2 = t2.col2)
group by t1.col1,
         t1.col2;

COL1 COL2       COL3
---- ---- ----------
11   00             
AA   BB            1
EE   FF            4
YY   ZZ            9
```

N.B. These could return different results if there happened to be more than one row that met the highest priority available join condition. The first query would return each row with a (potentially) different col3, whereas the second query would return just one row, with the lowest available col3 value.

---

What would you expect to see if T2 contained:

```
COL1 COL2       COL3
---- ---- ----------
AA   BB            1
AA   CC            2
CC   BB            3
GG   FF            4
GG   HH            5
EE   HH            6
XX   YY            7
XX   WW            8
YY   RR            9
YY   SS           10
```

The first query will give you:

```
COL1 COL2       COL3
---- ---- ----------
11   00             
AA   BB            1
EE   FF            4
YY   ZZ           10
YY   ZZ            9
```

The second query will give you:

```
COL1 COL2       COL3
---- ---- ----------
11   00             
AA   BB            1
EE   FF            4
YY   ZZ            9
```

Comment: Hi, Putting your code through seems like it will be correct (Will need to point t1 and t2 at my views and tables to confirm) but can you please explain the advantages / disadvantages of using either solution?

Comment: It kind of depends on what you want to happen in the case where there's more than one match for a join - eg. if in T2 there was a row of (col1, col2, col3) = ('YY', 'PP', 10), the first query would return two rows for t1 (col1, col2) = ('YY', 'ZZ) with col3 = 9 and 10 respectively, whereas the second would return just one row, with col3 = 9.

Comment: I followed solution 2 but had t1 defined as (select * from view1) t2 (select * from view2) and then replaced the col names. I hit a snag on Col3 however - should this be a valid existing column in view 2? I did this (picked a column at random) and the view compiled, however when selecting where rownum < 2 took a while (> 5 seconds so I killed the query in case it hit a recursive snag). For info: view1 has a few million rows and view2 has >500,000.

Comment: if col3 is what you're wanting to display against the t1 rows, then yes, it would need to be a column either from the view2 or derived in the t2 subquery. Also, I wouldn't necessarily expect this to run particularly quickly.

Comment: I have managed to alter the above by only pulling back col1 and col2 for t1 which resulted in a much better performance. Perhaps I over simplified my example but what I also wanted to do was pull back t2.col4 t2.col5 t2.col6 etc. and not just col3 - what adjustments need to be made? Do I need a pseudo column whereby I pull back (col3 col4 etc.) from view2 based on rownum or is it easier than this?

Comment: Update to the above - I got it to pull back the other columns by adding the same 'min' statement with col4 instead of col3 and repeated for the remaining columns. Is this the easiest / correct way of solving this?

Comment: it's one way of doing it, certainly! It really depends on what you want the results to be, though.

Comment: I've updated my answer to indicate the differences between the two queries. Depends on what you're expecting to see for duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this method, which chains together the result sets of three common table expressions, each of which implements a different join and checks whether the rowid of the row in T1 has already been projected from a successful join:

```
with
  first_join as (
    select t1.col1,
           t1.col2,
           t2.col3,
           t1.rowid
    from   t1 join t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2),
  second_join as (
    select t1.col1,
           t1.col2,
           t2.col3,
           t1.rowid
    from   t1 join t2 on  t1.col2 = t2.col2
    where  t1.rowid not in (select rowid from first_join)),
  third_join as (
      select t1.col1,
             t1.col2,
             t2.col3,
      from   t1 join t2 on  t1.col1 = t2.col1
      where  t1.rowid not in (select rowid from first_join union all
                              select rowid from second_join))
select col1, col2, col3 from first_join  union all
select col1, col2, col3 from second_join union all
select col1, col2, col3 from third_join
```

Comment: Some issues with this: 1. It doesn't include the rows where there are no joins. 2. There's an extra comma after `t2.col3` in the third_join subquery and 3. you need to alias the rowid's in each subquery, and reference those in the `select rowid` subqueries). I guess an extra union all to select those where `t1.col1 != t2.col2 and t1.col2 != t2.col2`?

Comment: Unpredicted issue in that 't1' is actually a view so when I mocked it up I got view compilation errors: ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table   Will try the other suggested answer now @Boneist

Comment: David's query does have some syntax issues as I mentioned in my comment above, but if your t1 and/or t2 are views, then you'd have to find some other way of giving a unique identifier to the row; possibly you could do this as something like: `t1 as (select row_number() over (order by col1, col2) rn, col1, col2 from your_t1_view)` and then referencing that everywhere else?

Comment: @bobdylan Well, it's not that it's unpredicted that it's a view, it's that you said that they are tables. It's really important that if you're going to ask people to put time in on your problems that you describe it correctly.

Comment: You get that error if t1 / t2 are tables; it's the reference to the rowid that does it - you need to alias it in the first_join and second_join subqueries.